Spring Boot does not return anything in ItemMedium Entity
I am trying to get the contents of the ItemMedium table which has the following attributes (item_id and medium_id are foreign keys from Item and Medium table).
@Entity(name = "ITEM_MEDIUM")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class ItemMedium {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("ITEM_MEDIUM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ITEM_MEDIUM_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ITEM_MEDIUM_SEQ", sequenceName = "ITEM_MEDIUM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long itemMediumId;
    @JsonProperty("ITEM_ID")
    private Long itemId;
    @JsonProperty("MEDIUM_ID")
    private Long mediumId;
    @JsonProperty("ARCHIVE_STATUS")
    private String archiveStatus;
    @JsonProperty("TYPE")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("STATUS")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("QUANTITY")
    private Long quantity;
    @JsonProperty("START_CONSUMPTION_DATE")
    private Date startConsumptionDate;
    @JsonProperty("END_CONSUMPTION_DATE")
    private Date endConsumptionDate;
    @JsonProperty("CREATE_DATE")
    private Date createDate;
    @JsonProperty("LAST_MODIFIED")
    private Date lastModified;
}

However, it does not return anything when I try to get all contents in the repository and Postman shows an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

You need to annotate the relationship between the tables-
@ManyToOne or
@OneToMany or
@OneToOne

Try updating relationship like this
public class ItemMedium {
    @JsonProperty("ITEM_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Item itemId;
}

or
public class ItemMedium {
    @JsonProperty("ITEM_ID")
    @OneToMany
    private List<Item> itemId;
}

or
public class ItemMedium {
    @JsonProperty("ITEM_ID")
    @OneToOne
    private Item itemId;
}

Similarly do this for Medium too.
